# Submit form: Assert that the DOM is completely rendered

Tags: angularjs

I’d like to submit a form but add some hidden inputs first.  The hidden inputs are added with a ng-repeat. Eventually they will be rendered, but how can I be sure that the DOM is already updated prior to triggering the submit event?

partial:

```html
<form ng-submit="addValuesAndSubmit()">
  <input type="hidden" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" ng-repeat="(name, value) in order">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

controller:

```js
$scope.addValuesAndSubmit = function() {
  $scope.order = { param1: 1, param2: 2 };
  // TODO: wait until form is rendered
  // there should be two <input type="hidden"> now
  // trigger submit action
};
```

As I understand it, a post-linking function for a directive could be used for this.  Am I right or am I missing something obvious?

EDIT:  The form data needs to be posted to an external website, redirecting the browser to the response.  It’s a payment integration where I calculate an HMAC on the server, add it to the form as a hidden element and then post it to the payment provider.  The implementation of  $http.post() seems not to do that redirect but returns the response instead.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular apps, you often want to submit your model, rather than extract your data from form elements. I.e., use ng-model to specify $scope model object properties, then submit that model object via ng-submit.  It would seem to me that you already have access to `order` in your $scope, since you are trying to get your associated view to use it.  So you probably don't need to wait for the view to update -- just use `order` directly in your addValuesAndSubmit() function.

Comment: The form needs to be submitted in a classical way which is not possible with angular at this moment.  Witold Szczerba proposes the same as me, a directive with a link function and some dirty DOM append here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/angular/form$20submit/angular/1wrnj7y-0O4/gK55C0PuwRsJ  Seems to be the only way …